# How to make POST http request with HTTP Basic Auth in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I am using React (with `create-react-app`) to crop an image and edit it. When finished, I want it to be compressed using the [tinyPNG API](https://tinypng.com/developers/reference), which is a wonderful tool and provides great png/jpg compression.

### Goal:

In my app I have got a `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA...` image. Within the [tinyPNG API](https://tinypng.com/developers/reference) I see two important steps to make a successful API call:

1. [Use HTTP Basic Authentication](https://tinypng.com/developers/reference#authentication)

> All requests require an Authorization header that contains a Base64 digest of the authentication string `api:YOUR_API_KEY` where `YOUR_API_KEY` is the key that can be found on your API account page.

2. [Compress image making a POST request](https://tinypng.com/developers/reference#compressing-images) with my Image as [Binary]

> POST /shrink HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: api.tinify.com
>
> Authorization: Basic YXBpOmFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6MDEyMzQ1
>
> [binary]

**Side question**: Is my `data:image/png;base64,...` string already "binary", or do I have to convert it to be binary?

How can I make the requested Http POST request using my image as `data:image/png`?

---

### My approach:

To make it easier for myself, I thought using [**Axios**](https://github.com/axios/axios). I have generated my own `API_KEY` and my `data:image/png;base64,...` stored as `imageSource`. Than I have tried to create my API call using Axios:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://api.tinify.com',
  withCredentials: true,
  auth: {
    username: api:MY_API_KEY',
  },
  data: {
    source: {
      url: imageSource, // data:image/png;base64,...
    },
  },
})
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

which always gives me an error:

> Failed to load https://api.tinify.com/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

I guess this means, that my HTTP Basic Authentication does not work? If so, what did I do wrong? Its confusing, that tinyPNG does not want a username and/or password, but an `api:MY_API_KEY`.

Although, how can I send my `data:image/png;base64`? Can I pass it as a "url" using source ([second example "Example upload from URL"](https://tinypng.com/developers/reference#compressing-images)), or do I have to pass it as Binary ([first example "Example upload from file"](https://tinypng.com/developers/reference#compressing-images)?

I appreciate any help achieving a successful response from the tinyPNG API.

Best regards and thanks for reading about my problem.

Comment: You need to include CORS headers in your request or on server, React no longer allows Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), and get away for chrome is CORS extension. Read more at [Enable CORS](https://enable-cors.org/)